# 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: apt, package-management, proxy, bashrc

I am trying to install a [library](https://openkim.org/doc/usage/obtaining-models/) but i am getting this error:

> $ sudo apt-get install libkim-api-dev
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> The following additional packages will be installed:
> libkim-api2
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
> libkim-api-dev libkim-api2
> 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 490 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 2,104 kB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
> Err:1 http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libkim-api2 amd64 2.1.3-5build1
> 503  Service Unavailable [IP: 10.10.78.61 3128]
> Err:2 http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libkim-api-dev amd64 2.1.3-5build1
> 503  Service Unavailable [IP: 10.10.78.61 3128]
> E: Failed to fetch http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kim-api/libkim-api2_2.1.3-5build1_amd64.deb  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 10.10.78.61 3128]
> E: Failed to fetch http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kim-api/libkim-api-dev_2.1.3-5build1_amd64.deb  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 10.10.78.61 3128]
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

The bashrc file has the following relevant content: `export https_proxy=https://proxy61.iitd.ernet.in:3128 export HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy61.iitd.ernet.in:3128 export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy61.iitd.ernet.in:3128 export http_proxy=http://proxy61.iitd.ernet.in:3128` .

My system proxy details are as follows: `For non-browser Applications (Proxy_Name: proxy61.iitd.ac.in Proxy_IP: 10.10.78.61 Proxy_port: 3128)`. The sources.list file has been changed with the following commands:`deb http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse deb http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse deb http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse deb http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse` .

I am able to access the internet from the browser however not able to download any package. What is the fix for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) Follow this, and use the server for United States. Later, change back to a server for India (there are several servers for India, and it seems that the one you are using is down).

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Cut past all text into the body of the question via edit.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I am inside a proxy server. So this link doesn't help. Thanks though!

Comment: @David I have made the edits.

Comment: ... behind a proxy and you're using a private repo. **THAT** should have been part of the question. Together with more information... e.g. if you can access http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu from a browser. Maybe port 80 ist blocked for you. However, as far as internal network issues are concerned, it might be difficult to help out and I guess you should rather ask your IT department.

Comment: @pLumo no i am not able to access  repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu from a browser.

Comment: Please don't add valuable information in comments, but edit your questions instead. But I say it again. You should rather ask your IT department that has installed or advised you to install these repos.

Answer (score 0):

**In short: Check your settings and contact your proxy provider.**

[EDIT] In your situation, you cannot connect to an APT mirror *inside* of the proxy network. CHeck your own network settings, or contact your proxy provider for details.

---

###### So, how to change?

If you are using GNOME, use the `software-properties-gtk` tool. [There is one existing question entity using this method.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Give me more information about your computer (is it a server, if not, which Desktop Manager environment are you using) to allow me to give more targeting answers.

Comment: My team mates are able to access the same apt source though. And when i try  nslookup i get the follwing response: Server:  127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: repo.iitd.ernet.in
Address: 10.10.30.1

Note that i am working under a proxy server.

Comment: Then, check your other settings that might affect your network. Try to contact your proxy provider too.